# Unused argument (sep=";") error happens with all CSV files

Tags: r, csv, readr

I'd like to open a random csv-file like New_York_City_Leading_Causes_of_Death.csv (just a dummy, from a tutorial but happens with my own data the same way; replaced , with ;)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3usf8y75vz2cpj4/New_York_City_Leading_Causes_of_Death.csv?dl=0

The outline says:
Error in read_csv("New_York_City_Leading_Causes_of_Death.csv", sep = ";") : 
  unused argument (sep = ";")

I created several csv-files to debug
I tried readr::read_csv as well as utils::read_csv -> both same problem 
I made sure that csv-file and .r are in the same folder 
I am using a pc by the university (maybe there's the bottleneck?)

**Thank you in advance :)**

```
library(utils)
library(utf8)

df <- read_csv("New_York_City_Leading_Causes_of_Death.csv", sep = ";" )
head(df)
```

That's the error message I get:

> Error in read_csv("New_York_City_Leading_Causes_of_Death.csv", sep = ";") : 
>     unused argument (sep = ";")

I expect the output to be a data-frame.

Comment: I found the solution to my problem.

readr::read_csv doesn't work - however
utils:read.csv does its job quite well

working: df <- utils::read.csv("New_York_City_Leading_Causes_of_Death.csv", sep = ";" )

still with error (see above): df <- readr::read_csv("New_York_City_Leading_Causes_of_Death.csv", delim = ";")

Comment: there is no `sep =` argument in `read_scv` function. and your `CSV` file is separated by `,` not `;`. please try `read.csv`

Comment: Iman, even with delim in read_csv it is not working. I will go along with read.csv in the future.

Comment: try `read_csv("New_York_City_Leading_Causes_of_Death.csv")`

Comment: as I said the .csv is just a dummy and I am working in RL with a semicolon-based csv-file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `utils` package only has the `read.csv()` function--notice the `.` instead of a `_`. As for `readr`'s `read_csv()` function, it does not have a parameter called `sep`. This is why an error message about having an unused argument `sep` appears every time you run your code.

I tried executing just `read_csv('New_York_City_Leading_Causes_of_Death.csv')` without any arguments and was successfully able to read in the following `tibble`:

```
# A tibble: 1,094 x 7
    Year `Leading Cause`                                 Sex   `Race Ethnicity`    Deaths `Death Rate` `Age Adjusted Dea~
   <dbl> <chr>                                           <chr> <chr>               <chr>  <chr>        <chr>             
 1  2010 Assault (Homicide: Y87.1, X85-Y09)              M     Black Non-Hispanic  299    35.1         35.5              
 2  2011 Mental and Behavioral Disorders due to Acciden~ M     Not Stated/Unknown  5      .            .                 
 3  2011 Diseases of Heart (I00-I09, I11, I13, I20-I51)  M     Black Non-Hispanic  1840   215.7        268.3             
 4  2008 Certain Conditions originating in the Perinata~ F     Other Race/ Ethnic~ .      .            .                 
 5  2014 Accidents Except Drug Posioning (V01-X39, X43,~ F     Hispanic            64     5.1          5.4               
 6  2007 Intentional Self-Harm (Suicide: X60-X84, Y87.0) M     Not Stated/Unknown  5      .            .                 
 7  2012 Accidents Except Drug Posioning (V01-X39, X43,~ M     Black Non-Hispanic  152    17.8         18.6              
 8  2009 All Other Causes                                M     Asian and Pacific ~ 220    43.1         56.1              
 9  2013 Diseases of Heart (I00-I09, I11, I13, I20-I51)  F     Asian and Pacific ~ 437    72.8         81.8              
10  2014 Accidents Except Drug Posioning (V01-X39, X43,~ M     Other Race/ Ethnic~ 12     .            .                 
# ... with 1,084 more rows
```

Alternatively, for faster performance on larger datasets, consider using `data.table::fread()`. The `fread()` function from the `data.table` package allows you to specify the delimiter to be `;` using the argument `sep = ';'`,. 
Do note that `fread()` can only return a `data.table` or a `data.frame`. By default, `fread()` returns a `data.table`, but can return a `data.frame` if the argument `data.table = FALSE` is passed in. However, if you would prefer working with a `tibble`, you can simply wrap the `fread()` call in `as_tibble()`.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me! My solution was to change read_csv for read.csv

My example:

instead of
X1_bank_full <- read_csv("C:/Users/User Name/Downloads/1-bank-full.csv", sep=";")

correct one is:
X1_bank_full <- read.csv("C:/Users/User Name/Downloads/1-bank-full.csv", sep=";")